# How to use Components in Laravel 5.1 as we do in Cakephp?

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have just moved towards la-ravel 5.1, 
as we use components in Cakephp, I want to know how to use such type of components in la-ravel.

Any help would be really appreciated.